# Trying to Write a program that reads a file containing a list of numbers, and displays the sum

Tags: python-3.x

```
def sum_list(name):
    num = []
    with open(name) as file:
        for line in file: 
            line = line.strip()
            num.append(int(line))
    sum = 0 
    for i in num: 
        sum = sum + i; 
    print("Sum of numbers : "+str(sum))
name = input("Enter path of file: ") 
sum_list(name)
```

it gives me the error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'def sum_list(name):'
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/Ghost/Documents/Anaconda/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/Ghost/Documents/Anaconda')
>
> File "D:\New
>   folder\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 704, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "D:\New
>   folder\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 108, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/Ghost/Documents/Anaconda/untitled0.py", line 12, in
>   
>       sum_list(name)
>
> File "C:/Users/Ghost/Documents/Anaconda/untitled0.py", line 6, in
>   sum_list
>       num.append(int(line))
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'def
>   sum_list(name):'

Comment: Show the full backtrace (because this runs find for me if you remove all the file handling stuff). You should also show an example file that fails.

Comment: Actually, that is a valid use of `input`. Not sure what is going on with that, but simplify and show the backtrace if you still need help. Try to reduce the problem to the smallest [mcve].

Comment: i've added my traceback

Comment: Welcome, Carl. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Those chatty "bump" and "thank you" comments are not appropriate for our format. We're not a discussion forum.